# Bar chart is showing lines (thin bars) instead of bars [SOLVED]

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to display a stacked bar chart with dates as xAxis. it display the number of sport session by type of sport.
The idea is to have for a specific time range the number of sessions displayed. For example for the last 4 weeks, the number of sessions per day will be displayed, and for the last 12 weeks, it will display the number of sessions per week.

These values are being calculated and displayed fine. The issue is that they are displayed as a 1px wide bar, instead of a "wide" automatically calculated bar width.

If someone have an idea how this fix this kind of issue... please help!

Data are structured as follows. I only show concerned data

```js
const sessions_summary = [
  {
    activity_name: 'regular_biking',
    date_time: '2020-03-18T15:57:47.853Z',
    // ...
  },
  {
    activity_name: 'swimming',
    date_time: '2020-03-18T15:57:47.853Z'
  },
  {
    activity_name: 'running',
    date_time: '2020-03-19T15:57:47.853Z'
  },
  // ...
];
```

Crossfilter:

```js
const ndx = crossfilter(sessions_summary);
const Dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return d3.timeDay(new Date(d.date_time));
});
```

Scaletime:

```js
const today = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
const minDate = d3.timeDay(
  new Date(
    new Date().setDate(
      today.getDate() - parseFloat(timeranges[timerange_name]) // 7 or 30 or 90 or 180 or 360 : number of days, depends on the interval selected in Select Entry
    )
  )
);
let maxDate = d3.timeDay(today);
maxDate = d3.timeDay.offset(maxDate, 1);
const scaletime = d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]);
Chart.x(scaletime);

const interval = intervals[timerange_name]; //  d3.timeDay or d3.timeWeek or d3.timeMonth, depending on the choice made in Select Entry
Chart.xUnits(interval);
```

Group:

```js
const types = [...new Set(sessions_summary.map(session => session.type))];
Group = Dimension.group(function(k) {
  return interval(k);
}).reduce(
  function(p, v) {
    if (v.type in p.types) {
    p.types[v.type]++;
    } else {
    p.types[v.type] = 1;
    }
    return p;
  },
  function(p, v) {
    p.types[v.type]--;
    if (p.types[v.type] === 0) {
    delete p.types[v.type];
    }
    return p;
  },
  function() {
    return {
    types: {}
    };
  }
);
Chart.group(Group, types[0], sel_stack(types[0])).render();
for (let i = 1; i < types.length; i++) {
  Chart.stack(Group, types[i], sel_stack(types[i]));
}
```

Bar Chart:

```js
const Chart = dc.barChart('#sessions_chart');
Chart.width(968)
  .height(240)
  .elasticY(true)
  .margins({
    left: 40,
    top: 10,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 40
  })
  .gap(5)
  .centerBar(true)
  .round(d3.timeDay.round)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .xUnits(d3.timeDays)
  .brushOn(false)
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .renderVerticalGridLines(false)
  .dimension(Dimension)
  .title(d => {
    return (
      'Date: ' +
      new Date(d.key).toDateString() +
      '\n' +
      'Sessions: ' +
      Object.keys(d.value.types)
    );
  });

Chart.legend(
  dc
    .legend()
    .x(40)
    .y(465)
    .gap(10)
    .horizontal(true)
    .autoItemWidth(true)
);
Chart.render();
```

Complete code can be found on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicodel/aLn43vho/)

Thanks in advance

[SOLVED]

The issue was the double `xUnits`, and the wrong use of `d3.TimeDay` instead of `d3.TimeDays`.

Comment: Bar width is controlled by `xUnits` so make sure this matches your data. You don't show your x scale or how you initialize crossfilter, so I'm not sure what kind of data you are trying to show here. If you can't figure it out, please edit your question to include that code.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Gordon. I added code to the post.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. You are initializing `.xUnits` twice, and if the comment is correct, the one in your "Scaletime" section is incorrect. Note the difference between `d3.timeDays` (used for units) and `d3.timeDay` (used for quanitization / dimension initialization). If scaletime is initialized after the chart, that could be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon! It works. I removed the `const interval = intervals[timerange_name]; //  d3.timeDay or d3.timeWeek or d3.timeMonth, depending on the choice made in Select Entry
Chart.xUnits(interval);` and bars are WIDE. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.